# Unable to permit params for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have this in my controller after upgrade to devise 3.5:

```
class MyController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    }
  end
```

And I still have the errors "email can't be blank, password can't be blank", etc. On post in "params" I have:

```
> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fdsfdsfd",
 "user"=>
  {"first_name"=>"fdsf",
   "last_name"=>"fdsf",
   "email"=>"something@gmail.com",
   "password"=>"fdsfdsfdsfds",
   "var1"=>{"var11"=>"33243", "var12"=>"7"},
   "var2"=>{"var21"=>"fdsfds", "var22"=>"3243243",},
   "var3"=>"fdsfsfds",
   "accept_terms"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Sign Up",
 "controller"=>"my",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Why the error then?

Comment: Are they validation errors?

Comment: Params just allows the fields to be permitted. Validations is something that happens within your model, so you should be looking there.

Comment: have you tried having an empty controller you should not need anything else unless you have a nested form